# in句とorder by を使用した場合に複合indexが使われていてもfile sortが発生してしまう

Tags: mysql, sql

以下のようなテーブルがに対してid, positionで複合indexを追加します。

```
+------+----------+
| id   | position |
+------+----------+
|    1 |        1 |
|    2 |        2 |
|    3 |        5 |
|    4 |        4 |
+------+----------+

show index from test;
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| Table | Non_unique | Key_name | Seq_in_index | Column_name | Collation | Cardinality | Sub_part | Packed | Null | Index_type | Comment | Index_comment |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
| test  |          1 | idx      |            1 | id          | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
| test  |          1 | idx      |            2 | position    | A         |           4 |     NULL | NULL   | YES  | BTREE      |         |               |
+-------+------------+----------+--------------+-------------+-----------+-------------+----------+--------+------+------------+---------+---------------+
```

この状態で以下のようなクエリを発行すると複合indexが使われているように見えますがfilesortが発生してしまいます。なぜfilesortが発生してしまうのでしょうか？また、filesortを回避する方法はありますでしょうか？

```
mysql> explain
    -> select
    ->   *
    -> from
    ->   test
    -> where
    ->   id in (1,3,4)
    -> order by position;
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
| id | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows | Extra                                    |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
|  1 | SIMPLE      | test  | range | idx           | idx  | 5       | NULL |    3 | Using where; Using index; Using filesort |
+----+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+------+---------+------+------+------------------------------------------+
```

Answer (score 1):

複合indexの`idx`は`id`順でソートした上で重複した部分についてのみ`position`順でソートされているのではないでしょうか。ですので`order by position`を実現するにはソートせざるを得ないです。

`idx`を`id, position`の順を逆転させて`position, id`にすればソートは不要になりますが、今度は`where id in (1,3,4)`の検索に使えなくなってしまい本末転倒です。ですのでソートは必須と思います。